# Make nginx avoid cache if response contains Vary Accept-Language

Tags: nginx, cache, http-headers

The cache module of nginx version 1.1.19 does not take the `Vary` header into account. This means that nginx will serve the same request even if the content of one of the fields specified in the `Vary` header has changed.

In my case I only care about the `Accept-Language` header, all the others have been taken care of.

How can I make nginx cache everything **except** responses that have a `Vary` header that contains `Accept-Language`?

I suppose I should have something like

```
location / {
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

    if ($some_header ~ "Accept-Language") { # WHAT IS THE HEADER TO USE?
         set $contains_accept_language # HOW SHOULD THIS VARIABLE BE SET?
    }

    proxy_no_cache $contains_accept_language

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}
```

but I do not know what is the variable name for "the `Vary` header received from the backend".

Answer (score 1):

As the relevant [ticket](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/118) has it, you have a few options:

1. Add $http_accept_language to the ​cache key.
2. proxy_no_cache $upstream_http_vary;

Comment: I do not want to cache things with `$http_accept_language` at all, so it is pointless to add it to the cache key.

Comment: Regarding `proxy_no_cache`, in my case all the responses have the `Vary` header, with that I would end up bypassing the cache for all the requests. Also, that ticked is outdated, in current nginx `proxy_no_cache` seems to require `proxy_cache_bypass` as well.